# Invalid key found in param call_to_actions for Facebook messenger on bot framework using node.js

Tags: node.js, facebook, azure, botframework

I am trying to add nested menu for the persistent menu. However, here is the issue i'm facing whereby stated invalid keys. I have tried referencing from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/persistent-menu too.

Could someone help me with this issue?

**My Code**:

```
{
  "setting_type" : "call_to_actions",
  "thread_state" : "existing_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "type":"postback",
      "title":"Main Menu",
      "payload":"main menu"
    },
    {
      "title":"Topics",
      "type":"nested",
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "title":"a",
          "type":"postback",
          "payload":"a"
        },
        {
          "title":"b",
          "type":"postback",
          "payload":"b"
        },
        {
          "title":"c",
          "type":"postback",
          "payload":"c"
        },
        {
          "title":"d",
          "type":"postback",
          "payload":"d"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Error Message**:

```
Persistent Menu: Failed. Need to handle errors.
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Invalid keys \"call_to_actions\" were found in param \"call_to_actions[1]\".","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"SOMEVALUE"}}
```

Comment: What version of the Graph API are you attempting to use?  I was unable to get the exact error message you are receiving.

Comment: @BlackSeraph v2.6

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to resolve the issue using curl from terminal. Code for the curl were took from https://www.techiediaries.com/messenger-bot-persistent-menu/.